# Could Madam Pomfrey heal Sectumsempra?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

Is Snape the only person who could heal the damage from Sectumsempra, a spell he invented, or could Madame Pomfrey undo the harm if she got there in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## There are multiple spells to heal the wounds caused by Sectumpsempra. So therefore Madame Pomfrey can heal wounds made by Sectumpsempra.

We first see Sectumsempra in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* with Malfoy and Harry in the bathroom, doing a sort of duel in which Malfoy nearly dies.

> There was a  loud bang and the bin behind Harry exploded;  Harry attempted a Leg-Locker Curse that backfired off the wall behind Malfoy’sear and smashed the cistern beneath Moaning Myrtle, who screamed loudly; water poured everywhere and Harry slipped as Malfoy, his face contorted, cried, “Cruci —”
>
> "SECTUMSEMPRA!” bellowed Harry from the floor, waving his wand wildly.
>
> Blood spurted from  Malfoy’s face and chest as though he had been slashed with an invisible sword. He staggered backward and collapsed onto the waterlogged floor with a great splash, his wand falling from his limp right hand.
>
> “No —” gasped Harry.

And we see Snape get there and heal Malfoy using a spell that sounds sort of like a song.

> The door banged open behind Harry and he looked up, terrified: Snape had burst into the room, his face livid. Pushing Harry roughly aside, knelt over  Malfoy,  drew his wand,  and traced it over the deep wounds Harry’s curse had made, muttering an incantation that sounded almost like a song. The flow of blood seemed to ease; Snape wiped the residue from Malfoy’s face and repeated his spell.  Now the wounds seemed to be knitting.
>
> Harry was still watching, horrified by what he had done, barely aware that he too was soaked in blood and water.
> Moaning Myrtle was still sobbing and wailing overhead. When Snape had performed his counter curse for the third time, he half-lifted Malfoy into a standing position.
>
> “You need the hospital wing. There may be a certain amount of scarring, but if you take dittany immediately we might avoid even that. ... Come. ...”
>
> He supported Malfoy across the bathroom, turning at the door to say in a voice of cold fury, “And you, Potter ... You wait here for me.”

There is a healing spell for Sectumsempra. Madame Pomfrey, as a skilled healer, would have a lot of knowledge of healing wounds. We see Molly Weasley heal George in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* with a different spell; not the one Snape used.

> “Harry, give us a hand!” called Hagrid hoarsely from the door, in which he was stuck again. Glad of something to do, Harry pulled him free, then headed through the empty kitchen and back into the sitting room, where Mrs. Weasley had staunched his bleeding now, and by the lamplight, Harry saw a clean, gaping hole where George’s the ear had been.
>
> “How is he?”
>
> Mrs. Weasley looked around and said, “I can’t make it grow back, not when it’s been removed by Dark Magic. But it could have been so much worse . . . He’s alive.”

This means that the spell Snape used is not the only spell that can be used to stop the bleeding. Even in our world aka. the Muggle world, there are numerous ways to stop bleeding. The appendages are a different matter though, as seen when George's ear is cut off.

Answer (score 8):

I'll take an educated guess: I think every healer could heal the damage of the curse as long as it does not sever limbs.

We learn in Deathly Hallows that Snape hits George with Sectumsempra and severs his ear.

> Where’s George?”
> “He lost an ear,” said Lupin.
> “Lost an — ?” repeated Hermione in a high voice.
> “Snape’s work,” said Lupin.
> “Snape?” shouted Harry. “You didn’t say —”
> “He lost his hood during the chase. Sectumsempra was always a
> speciality of Snape’s.
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter five - Fallen Warrior</sub>

Mrs. Weasly cannot make it regrow as it was severed by dark magic

> Mrs. Weasley looked around and said, "I can’t make it grow back,
> not when it’s been removed by Dark Magic.---"
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter five - Fallen Warrior</sub>

But still she can heal / seal the wound so that it stops bleeding.
If Mrs. Weasley was able to stop the bleeding then I think an experienced healer like Madame Pomfrey would have been able to do so as well.

Comment: I suspect that while the wounds can be treated, they can't be fully or perfectly healed/reversed with magic, which is what makes it Dark Magic. The bleeding could be stopped, but the wound can't be undone the same way, say, a mundane knife wound could be. Dark magic generally seems characterized by permanent, unavoidable, or unfixable results.

Comment: It’s also possible that Mrs. Weasley, an untrained housewife with a high school education, did not have the skills that madame pompfrey did.